# Is it a good practice to import shared sass variables into every vue component?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have many components in my Vue application that uses shared variables such as colors. Are there any negative ramifications of having each component import a global "variables.scss" file?

Comment: If it's needed for every component you may consider import it in you main app file instead of every component

Comment: try import your scss file: import('@/path/variables.scss'). if u want to use in all component you can import it in main.js file.

Comment: the first negative thing about importing it in every component that comes to my mind is that you may miss / forget about it in a new component

Comment: Since you are using Vue.js + Webpack (I hope) there will no problems after minification and your `variables.scss` code will not be copied million times (for each module where you import it). BUT sass files imported into component should typically only contain variables, mixins and functions. If the `variables.scss` file will contain any css code, or any code, which will be parsed into css, it WILL BE copied million times.

Comment: Going off of @BeniaminH also following KISS (Keep it simple stupid) / and DRY (don't repeat yourself), it'd be better to do it one place if it achieves the same as if you imported in all. Especially if it's being used in nearly every component it's more in line with the general component architecture than over importing.

Comment: I personally think it is very important that you know where your variables are coming from. Having 'global' variables makes this much less apparent.

Answer (score 1):

In general, being more explicit about dependencies is better than having some magical behavior.

In our case, it is mandatory since we are building very large scale application. When we move components to a different project or repo, due to explicit imports for SCSS variables files, we don't have to worry about finding all those magical variables. Also, sometimes nasty issues crop up when some of the SCSS files are external i.e. loaded from `node_modules` folders. Imagine, some other component overriding the value of the variable. By being explicit, variables are redeclared for that component and, these scenarios are greatly reduced.

But, if you are working with a small or medium-sized project with a smaller team then, implicit imports could be more beneficial.

So, there is no definite good/bad practice in regards to this. Chose one of the two but not both.